# WinUSB crashes with Error 1450 "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

Tags: c++, usb, winusb

i'm developing an Application in C++ for communicating via USB with a custom hardware based on a SAM-E70 which exchanges large amounts of data with the PC. While normally working fine, the WinUSB Driver will always crash after roughly two hours during a Transmission with Windows-Error 1450:

*"Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service".*

Visual Studio and the WinUSB Guide do not provide any information for this problem, so any idea is appreciated.

```
if (WinUsb_WritePipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle, list.Bulk.PipeOutId, bulk_tx_buf, 512, &bulk_tx_transferred, 0)) {
    //when transmission was successful, remove command from the stack
    command_list.pop();
}
else {
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    callback_error("Error during transmission, Code: " + std::to_string(err));
    call_terminate = true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a resource leak (e.g., handles, threads, GDI objects, something USB related). Somewhere you're allocating some Windows resource and not freeing it, causing Windows to eventually run out of that particular resource.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The only thing that might cause this is the receiving part, which happens async using an OVERLAPPED struct and is checked periodically as it does not support callbacks. There is no function to release these, or is it possible to clear OVERLAPPED structres directly somehow?